# Delete row in Postgres with USING statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

This first part works fine

```
SELECT
company_user.id,
company_user_company.company_id
FROM
company_user_company
RIGHT JOIN company_user
ON company_user_company.company_user_id = company_user.id
WHERE
company_user_company.company_id ISNULL;
```

I want to delete all rows that are returned from that statement. According to the documentation, I should be able to do this:

```
DELETE FROM company_user USING company_user_company
WHERE company_user.id = company_user_company.company_user_id AND company_user_company.company_id ISNULL;
```

That statement runs without error, but returns 0 rows.

Comment: `AND company_user_company.company_id IS NULL;` NULL compares unequal to anything. So `company_user.id = company_user_company.company_user_id` can never be true. Hint: use `EXISTS(correlated subquery)` [or NOT EXISTS(), I dont understand your intentions]

Comment: And IMHO most of your confusion is caused by using a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest, you use `NOT EXISTS()` instead of the crypric `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ... WHERE ...IS NULL`

---

```
SELECT *
FROM company_user cu
WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
        SELECT * FROM company_user_company cuc
        WHERE cu.id = cuc.company_user_id
        );

    -- If the above yields the correct rows to be deleted
    -- , you can delete them
    -- With *almost* the same query:
DELETE 
FROM company_user cu
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM company_user_company cuc
        WHERE cu.id = cuc.company_user_id 
        );
```